# How short setIntervals Should I do?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a facebook tab-page. Using javascript I how far down a user has scrolled in it's parent page (i'm inside an iframe and recieve the value via an api)

This is how I read the values. Right now though, it's a bit laggish. How often can I set the interval to? Is it possible and/or recommendet to go below 1ms?

```
setInterval(function(){
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info){
        $offset=info.scrollTop+'px';
        console.log($offset);
        $('#footer').css("top",$offset);
    });
},50);
```

Comment: What do you use these values for? What should you want to do with 1000 scrolling positions in one second?

Comment: You can't go below `1ms`. In fact the browser will likely enforce a minimum so that `1ms` won't be reached. Does `.getPageInfo()` make an AJAX request? If not, why does it accept a callback? The interval duration being too long is not likely the problem. The problem is more likely what you're trying to accomplish in that duration.

Comment: You can set it to 0. But as it was said, browser will perform it asap, but not in zero time nor <1ms. IMHO even with very fast device, it will run function once per 5ms.

Comment: .getPageINfo isn't a ajax-request. the delay that setInterval causes makes the thing lag a little bit wich makes it wobble when you scroll.